# rotating a 2d circle function

Tags: c++, c++11, directx, directx-9

im trying to add rotate to my function.

I have no idea how i can rotate it in my function

```
void draw_filled_circle(const RenderListPtr& render_list, const Vec2& position, float radius, CircleType type, Color color, float rotate){
    float pi;
    if (type == FULL) pi = D3DX_PI;         // Full circle
    if (type == HALF) pi = D3DX_PI / 2;     // 1/2 circle
    if (type == QUARTER) pi = D3DX_PI / 4;  // 1/4 circle

    const int segments = 32;
    float angle = rotate * D3DX_PI / 180;
    Vertex v[segments + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= segments; i++){
        float theta = 2.f * pi * static_cast<float>(i) / static_cast<float>(segments);
        v[i] = Vertex{
            position.x + radius * std::cos(theta),
            position.y + radius * std::sin(theta),
            color
        };
    }
    add_vertices(render_list, v, D3DPT_TRIANGLEFAN);
}
```

Comment: You need to specify what you mean by "rotate".    For rotation to be characterised by a single parameter, you will need to specify/assume something, such as what the centre of rotation is.   Also, you're using a variable-length array, which is not valid C++.

Comment: He is not using a variable array - it's a fixed sized array of 33 elements

Comment: @Peter the centre of rotation is centre of circle, just want to rotate it in 2d, so i can make it 45 or 180, incase im not drawing a full circle

Comment: @robthebloke - An array dimension requires an integer constant expression in C++.   Even though it is `const int`, the variable `segments` or expressions using it do not qualify.

Comment: @Peter its fixed size array, the compiler works itout as far as i know, my function works, i just cant work out how to rotate

Comment: @wihutamiz - if `rotate` is an angle in radians, just use `theta + rotate` (or `theta - rotate` depending on direction of rotation) as argument to trig functions.   If the argument is in degrees, convert to radians first.   Some C++ compilers incorrectly support VLAs.

Comment: @Peter const + const is a constexpr, so no, it is not a VLA.

Comment: @robthebloke.   A `const` named variable is not `constexpr`.

Comment: @Peter, If that were the case, this would be invalid:   constexpr int two = 1 + 1;

Answer (score 1):

In general you don't rotate anything by modifying the vertices directly. Instead, you use a matrix (The model-view-projection matrix) to transform the data. The 3 combined matrices boil down to:

- The Model Matrix: This is the matrix that is used to position and orient the geometry in world space. If it is just rotation you are after, then set this matrix to be a rotation matrix.
- The View matrix: This is the inverse matrix of your camera location.
- The projection matrix: this flattens the 3D vertex locations into 2D coordinates on the screen.

You usually combine all 3 matrices together into a single MVP matrix which you use to do all 3 transformations in a single operation. This doc explains some of the basics: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/the-direct3d-transformation-pipeline

```
D3DXMATRIX proj_mat; //< set with projection you need
D3DXMATRIX view_mat; //< invert the matrix for the camera position & orientation
D3DXMATRIX model_mat; //< set the rotation here
D3DXMATRIX MVP;
MVP = model_mat * view_mat * proj_mat; //< combine into a single MVP to set on your shader
```

If you *REALLY* want to rotate the vertex data in the buffer, then you can set the model_mat to be some rotation matrix, and then multiply each vertex by model_mat. The issue with doing that is that it's very slow to update (you need to rebuild the entire buffer each frame, and the GPU has circuitry design to transform vertices via a matrix)